# Swift segue passing nil string

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, segue

Well, in my app i have to set the value of another view var, but it seems that the val i assign this var is null when it passes through the segue, the 
code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    if segue.identifier == "DetailSegue"
    {
        let detailViewController = ((segue.destinationViewController) as RowViewController)
        let indexPath = self.table!.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        detailViewController.string = name.text
    }
}
```

and in the second view i have something like this:

```
var string: String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    descrip.text = string
    ...
```

Before you ask, name does have a value, but the segue seems to pass it nil :/ i really hope you guys could help me out on this one!

Comment: Can you provide more details about your attempted troubleshooting? Set breakpoints and step through the code using the debugger. At what point is a value different from what you expect?

Comment: It "seems" it passes it nil? Get some facts and then get back here.

Comment: well, i did the following to check that indeed it passes a nil value:
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
if string == nil {
   label.text = "it return null"
}

and the label changed  to the given text, so it proves it passes a nil value :/

Comment: And name does not have a value? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Basic debugging for a problem like this:

Step 1:

Check if the storyboard segue has the same identifier as the one you put in your code. Remember, lower case and upper case letters do matter.

Step 2:

Use plenty of println()s. This is one of the most useful, simple debugging tools in Xcode. You can print the values of your beginning label, your string on the next view controller, etc. Before you ask questions on Stack Overflow, try to figure it out for yourself -- that will make you a better programmer, and make you not have to rely on online communities as much.

Step 3:

Test out some other, simpler tasks with your problem to see if it is really a bug in Xcode or a mistake. Example, try to assign the value you are changing on the next view controller to a static piece of text instead of a label's text.

Hope this helped, and that you've fixed your problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I have given him some ways to debug his situation so he can fix it by himself and fix problems like it later if he runs into them. At the end, I give him a short note of how to ask questions on Stack Overflow. Most of the question is describing the debugging method.